# Select jsTree node without triggering select_node event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jsTree which when the user clicks on a node, it triggers the **select_node** event. However, I also have a list containing some entries with the id of the nodes in the jsTree. On selecting an entry in this list, I need to only select the node from the tree but without firing the **select_node** event. As per the documentation, select_node api has 3 parameters

> https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=(&f=select_node(obj [,
>   supress_event, prevent_open])

**obj**: mixed an array can be used to select multiple nodes
**supress_event**: 
Boolean if set to `true` the `changed.jstree` event won't be triggered
**prevent_open**: 
Boolean if set to `true` parents of the selected node won't be opened

However, it does not talk about suppressing the **select_node** event. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this event from firing?

Comment: Because I want to select this entry only to highlight it when the selection is made from the list.

Comment: I think you should post your code, better jsFiddle, to make your question clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. Temporarily disable your `select_node` event handler while you manually select a node from code.
2. Use the `changed` event instead of the `select_node` event and use the supress flag.

Comment: Sorry for accepting this so late. I used the second option.

Comment: `Changed` worked for me as well, although I am not quite sure why.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a better way to pull it off, but here's how I did it:

Instead of using the select_node function, I wrote a function which takes the ID of the node and then opens it, sets it as selected, and then recursively open the parent nodes.

```
$('#TreeDiv').jstree(true).open_node(actualId);
$('#TreeDiv').jstree(true).get_node(actualId).state.selected = true;
var parent = $('#TreeDiv').jstree(true).get_parent(actualId);
while (parent.length > 0) {
    $('#TreeDiv').jstree(true).open_node(parent);
    parent = $('#TreeDiv').jstree(true).get_parent(parent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following; it works for me

```
$('#TreeDiv').jstree("select_node", actualId, true);
```

According to the jsTree official documentation, the `select_node` method accepts a `Boolean` value as the second argument which indicates whether the corresponding event should be suppressed. See [this page](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=select_node&f=select_node(obj%20[,%20supress_event,%20prevent_open])).

Comment: This works only, if jstree has already finished loading, see https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1716